# Virtuoso server won't allow external calls

Tags: networking, hyper-v

I have the following code:

```
VirtuosoManager virtuoso = new VirtuosoManager("127.0.0.1", 1111, "http://dbpedia.org/", "dba", "dba");
Object results = virtuoso.Query("SELECT DISTINCT * WHERE { ?s ?p ?o } LIMIT 100");
```

which works fine if called from the same server, but if I change the IP to server IP and run this code from another client I get :

> *System.Net.Sockets.SocketException (0x80004005): No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it 127.0.0.1:1111*

which is werid because the IP is not **127.0.0.1** anymore, I changed it to the public IP of the server.

**strong text** works fine from client machine and I can run queries.

Comment: The issue was the virtual machine and the way network adapters were setup, I changed the network adapter type (In Hyper-V terminal manager) from public network to private network and it somehow changed the server's IP address and it fixed the problem. Running SPARQL queries is very slow now but at least it runs.

Comment: Your comment suggests that perhaps this question should simply be deleted, or at least completely recategorized, as the solution shows the problem had nothing to do with C#, .NET, RDF, Virtuoso, nor dotnetrdf.  (A different question about the "very slow SPARQL" might be worthwhile; I suggest you start with basic [Virtuoso performance tuning](http://vos.openlinksw.com/owiki/wiki/VOS/VirtRDFPerformanceTuning).)

Answer (score 0):

As reported by @user3277347 --

> The issue was the virtual machine and the way network adapters were set up. I changed the network adapter type (in Hyper-V terminal manager) from *public network* to *private network*. This somehow changed the server's IP address and fixed the problem.

Comment: Thanks for posting the answer I will re categorize this question.